# Is there a name for relations with this property?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, relations, equivalence-relations

Is there a name for relations $\rho : X \rightarrow Y$ such that for all $x,x' \in X$ and all $y,y' \in Y$ we have that the following conditions $$xy \in \rho$$ $$x'y \in \rho$$ $$xy' \in \rho$$ imply that $$x'y' \in \rho?$$

Here's a couple of alternative characterizations.

1. Define $\rho(x) = \{y\in Y \,|\, xy \in \rho\}$ for all $x \in X$. Then for all relations $\rho : X \rightarrow Y,$ we have that $\rho$ has the property of interest iff for all $x,x' \in X$ it holds that either $\rho(x) = \rho(x')$ or $\rho(x) \cap \rho(x') = \emptyset$.
2. Call a relation $\kappa : X \rightarrow Y$ *Cartesian* iff there exist $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$ such that $\kappa = A \times B$. Call two relations $\kappa$ and $\kappa$' strongly disjoint iff their images are disjoint, and their "left-images" are also disjoint. Then for all relations $\rho : X \rightarrow Y,$ we have that $\rho$ has the property of interest iff it can be expressed as a strongly disjoint union of Cartesian relations $X \rightarrow Y$.

A few observations:

- If a relation has the property of interest, so too does its converse.
- Every function has the property (and thus, so too does its converse).
- <strike>If two relations have the property, their composition does, too; thus, we obtain a category.</strike>
- The property is preserved under arbitrary strongly disjoint unions.

Comment: @Martin, I think (category-theory) is the best chance to get the answer if there is standard terminology for this. Added (terminology) and maybe OP can decide the rest.

Comment: @zyx, I was mistaken - they don't form a category.

Comment: I know, but thought the terminology knowledge might exist there.  Or not, it looks like something that may not have a standard name.  I am surprised that the natural codification of "function on quotients" is symmetric and leads to a bijection instead. Assuming that what's in the answer is correct...

Comment: I am also interested in the notion.  I asked on Math Overflow but didn't get any further: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146018/is-there-a-name-for-relations-with-this-property-and-the-category-of-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such relations are called *rectangular* in Section 5.2, page 669 of [Andrei A. Bulatov, Víctor Dalmau, *Towards a dichotomy theorem for the counting constraint satisfaction problem*, Information and Computation, Volume 205, Issue 5, May 2007, Pages 651-678](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ic.2006.09.005). They in fact define the property for higher arities, but it simplifies to your definition for binary relations.

Answer (score 3):

If the relation is seen as an undirected bipartite graph with edges joining $X$ and $Y$, the axiom is that a path of length 3 closes to a cycle of length 4.

In this form it is easy to check that "are both related to the same element in the other set (or equal)" is an equivalence relation on $X$ and on $Y$, and that if $x$ is related to $y$, all elements of $X$ equivalent to $x$ are related to all elements of $Y$ equivalent to $y$.  This is the condition for there to be quotients of the sets $X$ and $Y$ on which the relation descends to a one-to-one correspondence.

This can be expressed by saying that $\rho$ is/induces an "identification between quotients" of $X$ and $Y$.  That property is not closed under composition as far as I can see, but the other properties are true.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't proved it yet, but I am quite certain that its closed under composition. Can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: X quotient-identified with Y, and Y quotient-identified with Z, but the two Y quotients are completely different.  Or draw it using the bipartite graphs and see that two-step arcs from $x$ to $z$ to $x'$ to $z'$ don't create any paths of length 3 that complete to anything in the XY or YZ layers.

Comment: Hmm I'm still not getting it. Btw I sorely hope you're mistaken. Are you sure we're talking about the same notion of composition? I'm talking about the composition of relations, not the composition of graphs, if that helps.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what I need to draw? What are the cardinalities of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$? And what arcs do I draw?

Comment: path x1 to y1 to z1 to y2 to x2 to y3 to z2 (element relations as undirected edges) and take the X, Y and Z layers of cardinality 2,3,2.

Comment: Oh, nice. Good point.

Comment: This is very nice, though: a first order axiom that captures a natural second order property.  Where did the question come from?

Comment: Hmmm where did it come from. Good question. Well, I feel there's a lot of things we prove twice for functions, like we prove $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$, and we prove $f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$. It all seems very redundant, so I was thinking about just proving these things once for relations. Which works. But after pondering relations for a while, I concluded that they aren't a very natural generalization of the concept of a "function". So I wanted something more restrictive, which still covers functions and their converses. Didn't really work out though....

Comment: Zyx, you seem reasonably interested in the idea, so I'll let you know what I'm thinking - and, it's up to you whether or not to get back to me. Lets call the property of interest "property p". We can define the "closure" of a relation $\rho : X \rightarrow Y$ as the intersection of all relations $\lambda : X \rightarrow Y$ that have property p and which satisfy $\lambda \supseteq \rho$. Denote this $\mathrm{cl}(\rho)$. Now given relations $\rho : X \rightarrow Y$ and $\lambda : Y \rightarrow Z$, lets define that their composition is $\rho\lambda = \mathrm{cl}(\rho \circ \lambda).$

Comment: I think this notion of composition is associative on the class of all relations. However, since $\rho\lambda$ always has property p, we don't get a category. In particular, the identity morphisms are missing. To get them back, we need to restrict ourselves to relations with property p. So we have to consider the category whose objects are sets and whose arrows are relations with property p. The identity arrows in this category are precisely the usual ones....... So anyway, I don't know where I'm going with this, but if you have any thoughts, definitely let me know.

Comment: I will need to re-read what you just wrote, but something I wanted to write earlier is that a characterization of the property is that it is closed under forward and backward orbits.  This might be the same as what you just called the closure.

Comment: A correction to the answer: the relation $\rho$ induces a *partial* bijection between the $X$ and $Y$ quotients, because it is only a bijection on elements that participate in the relation.  Elements unrelated to any other element don't affect the property of $\rho$ descending to the quotients, but they are not placed in correspondence with anything.

Answer (score 1):

In regular categories, relations with this property are called *difunctional* or sometimes *Mal'cev* relations (or any other transliteration of the name). This terminology is used for example in the paper "Diagram chasing in Mal'cev categories" by Carboni, Lambek and Pedicchio, where it is also proved that a regular category is Mal'cev if and only if every relation is difunctional.

In the category of sets (or more generally any pretopos, see [this paper](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/27/1/27-01abs.html)), one can prove that a relation $R\subset X\times Y$ has this property if and only if it is a fibered product

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}R @>{\pi_Y|_R}>> Y \\ @V{\pi_X|_R}VV @VV{g}V \\ X@>>{f}> Z.\end{CD}$$

In fact is is then the fibered product $X\times_{X\sqcup_RY} Y$, where $X\sqcup_RY$ is the pushout of the span $X\leftarrow R\rightarrow Y$, which can be obtained as the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$ quotiented by the equivalence relation $R'$ defined for $x,x'\in X$ and $y,y'\in Y$ by :

- $(x,x')\in R'\Leftrightarrow (x,x')\in R\circ R^°$ or $x=x'$
- $(x,y)\in R'\Leftrightarrow (x,y)\in R$
- $(y,x)\in R'\Leftrightarrow (x,y)\in R$
- $(y,y')\in R'\Leftrightarrow (y,y')\in R^°\circ R$ or $y=y'$.

Using this construction it looks like we can obtain your second point.