# In a dagger category, what do we call an arrow $f$ such that $f \circ f^\dagger \circ f = f$?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, semigroups, monoid, dagger-categories

In a dagger category, what do we call an arrow $f$ satisfying $f \circ f^\dagger \circ f = f$?

In $\mathrm{Rel}$ (and, more generally, an [allegory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_%28category_theory%29)) this is straightforwardly equivalent to $f \circ f^\dagger \circ f \leq f$ (see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675725/does-f-leq-f-circ-f-dagger-circ-f-hold-in-an-arbitrary-allegory)). I have been calling this latter condition *rectangular* on the basis of the answer I recieved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391108/is-there-a-name-for-relations-with-this-property). However, I am interested in allegory-like structures where this equivalence breaks down, so a name for this condition not equal to 'rectangular' would be great.

Comment: Such an $f$ is called regular in semigroups and ring theory, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_semigroup and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring -- $f^\dagger$ is called an inverse or weak inverse in these situations.

Comment: @JackSchmidt, thank you, after a bit of thought I think I will adopt this terminology. The only issue that in a dagger category, from $f∘f^\dagger∘f=f$ we may deduce $f^\dagger \circ f \circ f^\dagger=f^\dagger.$ So such an $f$ necessarily has a "strong" inverse. Please comment if you have any ideas how to resolve this terminological issue.

Comment: In semigroups, that is called having an inverse, but you'll still need to define it to avoid confusion with $ff^\dagger=1$ and $f^\dagger f=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673952), what about [partial isometries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_isometry)?

Comment: Martin, is there a name in category theory for an arrow $f : X \rightarrow Y$ such that we can find another arrow $g : Y \rightarrow X$ satisfying $f \circ g \circ f = f$ and $g \circ f \circ g = g$? Or anything similar?

Comment: Von Neumann regular? (Again I'm just making a suggestion, I am not claiming that this is standard terminology.)